# One computer recognizes the other computer on the network while the other does not

Tags: windows-10, networking

I have two computers running Windows 10 connected to a router. Both are in the same Workgroup. One computer recognizes the other computer on the network while the other does not.
So on computer A in the network folder I can see the icon of computer B and access shared folders on that computer.
On computer B I cannot see the icon of computer A so cannot access it. It has appeared a couple of times only to disappear again.
Both C drives are shared. I have network discovery turned on on both computers as well as file and printer sharing. They can both ping each other however.

Things I have tried are:

```
AllowInsecureGuestAuth in registry  
Send LM & NTLM-use NTLMv2 in Local Security Policy  
SMB 1.0 in Windows Features  
ipconfig /release  
ipconfig /flushdns  
ipconfig /renew  
nbtstat -r  
netsh int ip reset   
netsh winsock
```

The following services set to automatic delayed start:

```
Computer Browser (Browser) (this I one I had to set as automatic not delayed)  
Function Discovery Provider Host (FDPHost)  
Function Discovery Resource Publication (FDResPub)  
Network Connections (NetMan)  
UPnP Device Host (UPnPHost)  
Peer Name Resolution Protocol (PNRPSvc)  
Peer Networking Grouping (P2PSvc)  
Peer Networking Identity Manager (P2PIMSvc)
```

Comment: I share machines regularly .   Look outside your list.  Make sure SMB is newest and install on both computers.  Make sure networking is the same on both computers (DHCP and one subnet). I have no need to delay services on startup. I have used in past but no need in several years changes to NTLM in security policies.  I do not ned to use the registry at all to share folders.  Make sure folders are shared to the other user on both machines.

Comment: I just set the newest SMB on both computers using the Powershell command:
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB2Protocol $true

For DHCP, both computers have obtain an IP address and DHS server address automatically set. Both have the same subnet mask. Folders are shared on both machines. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I’ll think about this some . No issues with several computers: Windows 10 and 11, Ubuntu, and Kali

Comment: If you hare sure everything else in your system is fine, you might consider backing up the errant computer and reinstalling Windows. Faster than finding a needle in a haystack. Everything here is working just fine (vanilla network settings).

Comment: I tried that before. The only time I got it working on both computers was when I was running Windows Server 2022 on both of them. Then I did zero setting up and it just worked.